# Python: Разделение строк внутри списка

Tags: python

У меня есть список:

```
description = ["# def get_list(self, message_body, conn):#object_get_list"]
```

Из этого списка, необходимо получить два параметра.

```
Old outcoming method name:
New outcoming method name:
```

Пример для выше переведенного списика :

```
Old outcoming method name: get_list
New outcoming method method name: object_get_list
```

Я знаю как получить "Old outcoming method name", но ума не приложу, как я могу получить "New outcoming method name".

Буду благодарен за помощь в решении, или за информацию касательно направления для изучения вопроса.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Когда я полагаю, что ваш список состоит только из одного элемента-строки, то так:

```
description[0].split("#")[-1]
```

---

Объяснение:

`description[0]` - первый (единый) элемент вашего списка - строка,
`split("#")` сделает из этой строки список из 3 строк:

- *перед* первым символом `#` (пустая строка),
- *между* символми `#`, и
- *после* второго символа `#` - **то, что вы хотите**

`[-1]` индекс последней из них - той, которую вы хотите.

Comment: Подскажите пожалуйста, а как реализовать разделение списка, который состоит из нескольких элементов строк?

Comment: IИспользуйте списковое включение `[desc.split("#")[-1] for desc in description]`

Comment: Благодарю за помощь.

Comment: @MrOldSir, не стоит.